# How strongly does $\int_1^X \frac{\exp(B/\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x} dx$ depend on $B$?

Tags: integration, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

As part of analysing an algorithm I stumbled upon the integral $\displaystyle \int_1^X \frac{\exp(B/\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x} dx$ as an approximation for the corresponding sum. Wolfram alpha gives the antiderivative in terms of non-elementary functions. This seems more trouble than it's worth since I'm only interested in a readable bound for the integral.

One very poor bound  comes from rounding the exponential up to $e^B$ and get $\displaystyle e^B \int_1^X \frac{dx}{\sqrt x}  = 2e^B(\sqrt X - 1) = O(e^B \sqrt X) $.

One better bound comes from breaking the intgral into two parts like this:

$$\displaystyle \int_1^X \frac{\exp(B/\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x} dx= \int_1^{B^2}\frac{\exp(B/\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x} dx + \int_{B^2}^X \frac{\exp(B/\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x} dx$$

For the first part do the same rounding up to get
$$  \int_1^{B^2}\frac{\exp(B/\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}\le e^B \int_1^{B^2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x} \le 2e^B \sqrt {B^2} = 2B e^B.$$
For the second part the denominator is small and we get

$$ \int_{B^2}^X \frac{\exp(B/\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x} dx \le \int_{B^2}^X \frac{e}{\sqrt x} dx = 2 e (\sqrt X - \sqrt {B^2}) \le 2e \sqrt X.$$

Putting it back together we can bound the original integral by $2Be^B + 2e \sqrt X$. We still have the exponential term but not it is a constant and not multiplied by the $\sqrt X$.

I wonder can we do any better than this? Can we replace the dependence on $B$ with something weaker?

Comment: I think the following might help. Consider the u sub $u = 1/sqrt(x)$. Then the integral is $2\int_{1/\sqrt{X}}^1 \exp(Bu)u^2 \ du$. Now the whole integral from $0$ to $1$ can be found explicitly and then the error term is $2\int_0^{1/\sqrt{X}}$. For this, a taylor series around $0$ gives you a good bound.

Answer (score 1):

*I do not know if this will answer your question.*

Effectively, after one integration by parts, we end with
$$I=\int_1^X\frac{e^{\frac{B}{\sqrt{x}}}}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx=-2 \left(B \,\text{Ei}\left(\frac{B}{\sqrt{X}}\right)-B\, \text{Ei}(B)-\sqrt{X}
  \, e^{\frac{B}{\sqrt{X}}}+e^B\right)$$
What is doable is to expand as a series around $B=0$; this would give
$$I=2\left( \sqrt{X}-1\right)+B\, \log (X)+
   \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}}\right)B^2+O\left(B^3\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find
$$
\int\frac{\exp(B/\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}dx=2\sqrt{x}\exp\left(\frac{B}{\sqrt{x}}\right)-2B\cdot\textrm{Ei}\left(\frac{B}{\sqrt{x}}\right),
$$
where
$$
\textrm{Ei}(z)=-\int^{\infty}_{-z}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt
$$
and then see at [Wikipedia Ei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)